# Gmail (Google Apps for Business) - sending email from a group address not working anymore?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

We've been using Google Apps for Business for several years. We want to send out email from a group address instead of an individual one, e.g. `teamA@example.com` instead of `JohnDoe@example.com` with John Doe belonging to teamA. Previously it was all working perfectly.

However, starting form this year something went wrong. We tried to use `Settings > Account > Add another address` to set up this functionality for new recruits. But, when Gmail asked the user to provide for authentication, we couldn't provide `teamA@example.com` as the "username" as it's not an actual gmail account, and the authentication wouldn't pass. If we fill out `JohnDoe@example.com` as authentication name, the setup can be completed, but then emails are sent with `JohnDoe@example.com` in the "from" field, instead of `teamA@example.com`.

Did something in Gmail change? Or did we somehow mess up the process?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

OK I seem to have found the issue. It seems that Google somehow [updated](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GyeMcHv1U-g%5B1-25-false%5D) its security policy this summer, and as a result, you have to

- First, use "add another email address" under JohnDoe@example.com to add teamA@example.com to JohnDoe@example.com, in which step you'll not be prompted to authenticate
- Then, go to your personal gmail and use "add another email address" on teamA@example.com, where you'll authenticate using JohnDoe@example.com Because the first step is done, now Gmail recognizes that JohnDoe@example.com has the right to send email as teamA@example.com, and authorizes your personal email account accordingly.

Comment: Can you clarify step one? What exactly are you adding?

Comment: @jetlej Sorry didn't see your comment. I was referring to adding the team address to the personal address within the organization, if that might still help later readers.